# Tumbleweed badge for an upvoted (not-answered) question?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414898/phing-sending-the-full-log-by-email) on sept 12th -- ie, more than 7 days ago ; right now, it has:

- 26 views *(was 24 or 25 until a few minutes ago, before I opened it)*
- no answer
- no comment

I was thinking I would get a tumbleweed badge (which description says "*Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week*") as a "consolation prize", but I haven't gotten one.

Out of curiosity, I was wondering why.

Is it because my question has been upvoted? I would have thought this meant "*not a too bad question*", and would have given even more meaning to the "consolation prize" idea.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/tumbleweed-criteria-not-documented-properly/61123#61123) The upvoter shot the tumbleweed, but I doubt it was in self-defense.

And yes, I don't think an upvote should invalidate it getting tumbleweed.

Comment: You mean, it might be like one of those Western shootouts where, shortly before the stroke of midday, everyone in the town is watching the black hat face the marshal, waiting for the bell to ring out, and the only thing moving is a tumbleweed…?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps 24 - 26 views in 7 days isn't considered "low" by the system's standards. The definition of "low" is very vague; I personally would like to know how that's calculated.

Comment: I would like to know too ^^ I searched a bit on meta, but the only info I found is "it's vague and it's on purpose"

Answer (score 1):

I think too many views kill the chance for the TW badge.

Comment: That it does, one of the requirements is low views.

Comment: I wouldn't have considered 25 views in more than 7 days as being "many" actually -- but you're probably right, I suppose :-(